# Auto populate login user name in SharePoint people picker column using InfoPath

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2010, infopath

I have two SharePoint list:

In **first list**, I am maintaining the 2 or more `approval` name's in people picker column.

In **second list**, I have approval people picker column.

Based on the login user name it should check in backup list(ie., First list) and if the user exist then it should auto populate display name in approval people picker column.

Answer (score 0):

You can add approvers to a SharePoint group. Check whether the current user is a member of this group in InfoPath. If the condition is true, set people picker field value to **userName()**. **userName()** is a built in InfoPath function which can be used to return the user id/ account id of the current user.

In the form, use **GetUserProfileByName** (SOAP Web service: /_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx) and **GetUserCollectionFromGroup** (SOAP Web service: /_vti_bin/UserGroup.asmx) methods to check if the current user is in the specific group.

[How to check if a user is a member of a SharePoint group in InfoPath](https://manojssharepointblog.wordpress.com/2015/02/26/how-to-check-if-a-user-is-part-of-a-sharepoint-group-in-web-based-infopath-form/)

Then in the rule, set a people picker field value to **userName()** with **Set a field’s value** action.

[image]
[image]